# how to redirect pages in jsf 2?

Tags: redirect, jsf-2

i have a simple menu on jsf:

```
 <h:panelGroup id="panelMenu">
    <h:form id="menuForm">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab">
        <li class="active"><h:outputLink value="contenido/Agrupaciones.xhtml"><h:outputText value="Agrupaciones" /></h:outputLink></li>
        <li><h:outputLink value="contenido/Usuarios.xhtml" ><h:outputText value="Usuarios" /></h:outputLink></li>
        <li><h:outputLink value="contenido/Modulos.xhtml" ><h:outputText value="Modulos" /></h:outputLink></li>
        <li><h:outputLink value="contenido/Roles.xhtml" ><h:outputText value="Roles" /></h:outputLink></li>
    </ul>
    </h:form>
    </h:panelGroup>
```

it works ok, but when im on one of my pages.. let say "users.xhtml" and from that page i go to another like "details" `<h:outputLink  value="../contenido/detalleUsuario.xhtml">`, when i click again in my principal menu to go back to "users"  the url looks like this:

contenido/contenido/Usuarios.xhtml when it should be contenido/Users.xhtml. so i get a "page not found error".

Comment: Your terminology is not correct. A redirect is a HTTP `3nn` response, but you've there just a bunch of GET links. Please fix the wrong terminology in your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`<h:link>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/h/link.html) instead of [`<h:outputLink>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/h/outputLink.html). The `<h:link>` treats the path as navigation case outcome and will always resolve it relative to the context path. So you can safely start the outcome with `/` without worrying about the context path.

```
<li class="active"><h:link value="Agrupaciones" outcome="/contenido/Agrupaciones.xhtml" /></li>
<li><h:link value="Usuarios" outcome="/contenido/Usuarios.xhtml" /></li>
<li><h:link value="Modulos" outcome="/contenido/Modulos.xhtml" /></li>
<li><h:link value="Roles" outcome="/contenido/Roles.xhtml" /></li>
```

Note that those links doesn't require a form at all. So the whole `<h:form>` as you've in your code is completely superfluous.